# solving a system of partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

My naive code looks like the one in the picture
My problem is when I run it, I dont get any result. No error is thrown my way either. I just get a typesetted version of the NDSolve command. How do I do this properly?

```
eqs = {{D[p[t, r], t] + Laplacian[o[t, r], r] == 0}, 
{p[t,r] == (1 + r^2)*D[o[t, r], t] - (1 + r^2)^-1 D[o[t, r], r]}};
vars = {p[t, r], o[t, r]};
bcndtns = {p[t, 1000] == 0, o[t, 1000] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][p][10, 1000] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][o][10, 1000] == 0};
NDSolve[{eqs, bcndtns}, vars, {t, 0, 1000}, {r, 0, 1000}]
```

> `NDSolve[{{{Laplacian[o[t, r], r] + Derivative[1, 0][p][t, r] == 0},  {p[t, r] == -(Derivative[0, 1][o][t, r]/(1 + r^2)) + (1 + r^2)* Derivative[1, 0][o][t, r]}}, {p[r, 1000] == 0, o[r, 1000] == 0,  Derivative[0, 1][p][10, 1000] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][o][10, 1000] == 0}}, {p[r, t], o[r, t]}, {t,  0, 1000}, {r, 0, 1000}]`

[image]

Comment: Usually that means Mathematica can't find a solution. I'm missing  initial conditions in your problem!?!

Comment: Post actual code (as `InputForm`) rather than an image of code so that it can be copy and pasted into a notebook.

Answer (score 4):

You had many problems. Always better to write each pde and its bc's and ic's each on its own line. This way you can see what you are doing. No need to use Laplacian. You have a pde with one spatial coordinate. Also need IC's which I set to zero. You can change if needed.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq1  =  D[p[t,r],t]==D[p[t,r],{r,2}]
eq2  =  p[t,r]==(1+r^2)*D[o[t,r],t]-(1+r^2)^- D[o[t,r],r]
vars =  {p[t,r],o[t,r]}
bc1  =  {p[t,1000]==0,(D[p[t,r],r]/.{r->1000})==0}
bc2  =  o[t,1000]==0
ic1  =  p[0,r]==0
ic2  =  o[0,r]==0

NDSolve[{eq1,eq2,bc1,bc2,ic1,ic2},vars,{t,0,10},{r,0,1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. with NDSolve it is better to use this form of call

```
vars={p,o}; (*notice change*)
NDSolve[{eq1,eq2,bc1,bc2,ic1,ic2},vars,{t,0,10},{r,0,1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]